# how to smooth bitmaps for drawable in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, paint

I create a Bitmap filled-circle with Paint and Canvas and then convert it to a drawable, which I then use as the background to an ImageView. But the image does not look smooth on the phone; the circle has ridges. How do I smooth out the image? I try changing the manifest to say `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` and then `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` but neither had any effect. I want the image's perimeter to look smooth. The ridges are there whether I use a Stroke or not. I also get the same problem whether I use `canvas.drawCircle` or `canvas.drawOval` with `RectF`

Comment: Are you setting the anti-alias flag when you create the paint object?

Comment: With the command : paint.setAntiAlias(true);

Comment: The anti aliasing works. Do you mind posting as a response so I can mark this thread as resolved?